# java.sql.SQLException: The statement is closed

Tags: java, sql, spring-mvc, ejb

I am using `sql server 2008 R2`. In that I am using a `Ejb stateless`. In that i am declaring a instance variable of my Database class and instantiated on either on the create method or at the instance variable also.

and when i call a execute a executeQuery method that throw an Exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: The statement is closed.

But it works fine if i define local variable of my database class object in the Ejb bussiness method .

I don't understand why that happens.

Comment: Show us some code?

Comment: please give us some code

Comment: As mentioned by previous users, please provide the code that you are using as the question currently cannot be accurately answered with the provided information.